# Computing the distributional derivative of a particular function

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, distribution-theory, weak-derivatives

Let us consider the function
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } x \in \mathbb Q \\
-1 & \text{if } x \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q
\end{cases}
$$

I have a main question about the distributional derivative of $f$. Let me split it into four thoughts/subquestions:

1. This function is not Riemann integrable because it is not continuous anywhere. **Is this right?**
2. This function belongs to $L^1_{loc}$ (just because $|f| = 1$ everywhere, **right?**).
3. As a  $L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$ function, $f$ can be identified with distribution   $T_f$ that act as
   $$\langle T_f,\varphi\rangle= \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)\varphi(x)dx, \quad \varphi\in \mathcal D(\mathbb{R}).$$
4. Every distribution has a distributional derivative. In the case of this function $f$, let's recall the definition of the distributional derivative $T_f '$:
   $$\langle T_f ', \varphi \rangle := -\langle T_f, \varphi'\rangle = -\int_{\mathbb R} f\varphi' dx, \quad \varphi\in \mathcal D(\mathbb{R}).$$
   Now, is it possible to **compute** this, that is
   $$
   \int_{\mathbb R} \big(1_{\mathbb Q}(x) - 1_{\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q}(x)\big) \varphi(x) dx
   $$
   **explicitly?** Is it only a distribution or also a **locally finite measure?**

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152192/discussion-on-question-by-zelda-computing-the-distributional-derivative-of-a-par); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.